# Entering value to a textbox among many textboxes if it is empty in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my program, there is a dropdown like below:

```
<select id='selectValue'>
<option>Value1</option>
<option>Value2</option>
<option>Value3</option>
<option>Value4</option>
</select>
```

Then, there are three textboxes like below:

```
<input type='text' id='textbox1' class='textbox'>
<input type='text' id='textbox2' class='textbox'>
<input type='text' id='textbox3' class='textbox'>
```

When I select a value from the dropdown, the value will be entered to one of the textbox which is empty. But a value should not be entered to multiple empty textboxes. **Note that, at first all textboxes are empty**.

What should be the jQuery or JavaScript code to achieve this?

**Update:**

I have done this so far.

```
$("#selectValue").on("change",function(){

    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        var textbox = "#textbox" + i;
    var nextTextbox = "#textbox" + (i+1);
        if(!$(textbox).val()){
            $(textbox).val(selectedValue);
        }
        else{
            $(nextTextbox).val(selectedValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: No idea to me what to start from? Should I use a loop?

Comment: yea have you tried something yet? we're not here to do your hw

Comment: @HiranmoyChatterjee Yes, you could use a loop. When the select event happens, find the first empty input box and put the text there.

Comment: I would recommend an event listener on `selectValue` which gets the selected option and puts it into an input that is empty

Comment: Well, get the value from the selected option in (in JavaScript or jQuery), then assign it to one of the textboxes (idk how you choose) if it's empty. You can easily google these steps

Comment: So the user can choose three values from the `<select>`, all at once or sequentially? What should happen if a fourth choice is made? And 'where to start?' break the task down into steps, and then search for solutions to each individual step. We're happy to *help*, but we're unlikely to do the whole of your work for you.

Comment: Show your effort. Try to get value from select option and set to textbox.

Comment: Use same class for textboxes you want to set value.

Comment: I have checked it. Why alerting 'More than one textbox is empty'? @RinoRaj

Comment: Your code is not working. Please see it. @RinoRaj

Comment: Can anyone say, why my question is downvoted? SO is for not only experts, it is also for new learners. I think this is a good question. I request the person who downvoted this to submit an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id='selectValue'>
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="Value1">Value1</option>
    <option value="Value2">Value2</option>
    <option value="Value3">Value3</option>
    <option value="Value2">Value4</option>
</select>

<input type='text' id='textbox1' class='textbox' />
<input type='text' id='textbox2' class='textbox' />
<input type='text' id='textbox3' class='textbox' />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#selectValue').on('change', function(){
   var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    if(selectedValue != '0'){
        var textboxes = $('.textbox');       
        for(var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++){
            if($(textboxes[i]).val() == ''){
                $(textboxes[i]).val(selectedValue);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqb9do42/1/)

Comment: @Hiranmoy Chatterjee, see if this satisfies your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now.

```
$("#selectValue").on("change",function(){

var selectedValue = $(this).val();

for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    var textbox = "#textbox" + i;
    if(!$(textbox).val()){
        $(textbox).val(selectedValue);
break;
    }
}
});
```